# How can I pass mouse events on a translucent JWindow to the JFrame underneath?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Firefox style drag and drop tabbed pane based on [this example](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/04/drag-and-drop-tabs-in-jtabbedpane.html). To implement the scaled tab images as you drag I am using a JWindow. I want the image to be visible when you drag anywhere on the desktop so I have to use a heavyweight component instead of drawing on the glass pane like most examples I have seen.

However, when I drag the JWindow captures mouse events and interferes with drag and drop listeners that are on the JFrame below. Is there a way I can get the JWindow to resdispatch the mouse events so they activate the drag listeners on the JFrame below (like would happen if I did use the glass pane)?

Comment: For now my workaround is to slightly shift the location of the JWindow so that the mouse pointer never touches it and mouse events are handled by the JFrames below but I would still be interested in any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this good article "[A well-behaved GlassPane](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/09/a_wellbehaved_g.html)" which may have some ideas for doing what you wish.